# Javascript regex to replace /*

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to replace a string.
I have tried this, which I thought would work, but it doesn't

```
string = "/*"
string.replace(/\/(?=\*)/g,"replaced")
```

I tried escaping the asterisk and leaving it alone but both didn't work.
Could somebody tell me the regex to replace `/*` and `*/` ?

Comment: please format your code properly next time

Answer (score 4):

The following should work:

```
/\/\*|\*\//g
```

Comment: Thanks, this didn't work straight away but i pasted it above everything else and then it did.

Answer (score 0):

Replace /* or replace */

```
var string = "/**"
string.replace(/(\/\*)|(\*\/)/g,"replaced")
```